# PL/SQL to find the grade change in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table asg_tab and grad_tab such as :

asg_tab

```
person_id  grade_id   full_name  start date      end date
1                           smith     01-Jan-2016    20-Feb-2016
1                001        smith     21-Feb-2016    31-Dec-4712
2                           will      01-Feb-2016    18-Mar-2016
2                004        will      19-Mar-2016    31-Dec-4712
```

grd_tab

```
grade_id  grade name
001       Band 1 
002       Band 2 
004       Band 3
```

Now in asg tab if there is any change in grade_id i have to create a query / function which will return the start_date and grade_name

I have created the following query for this :

```
SELECT  *
From    (
        Select  Person_id,
   Grade_Id,
                LAG(grade_id) OVER (PARTITION BY person_ID ORDER BY start_Date) AS prev_grade_line1,
                Row_Number() Over (Partition By Person_Id Order By Start_Date Desc) As Rn,
                Effective_Start_Date
                        From    asg_tab

        )
WHERE   rn = 1;
```

But this is also returning the grades when it is null for a person id in all start dates

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: Not sure how you got 2 upvotes. The question is not very clear. *if there is any change in grade_id*: How do you detect a *change*? Is it based on `full_name`, `assignment_id`? but with an older date? And why do you want a function? What if there are multiple rows with changes, what would the result look like?  Because a function can only return one value. Do you want it to return a table of values? What is your expected output?

Comment: @sstan - WE DETECT A CHANGE by looking at the previous row. if there is a grade_id change then that effective_start_date and name should be returned

Comment: So, for instance, what would you return for the 3rd row since the `grade_id` (`null`) is different from the previous row's `001`. And how do you determine a *previous row*, since database rows are unordered? How are the rows ordered?

Comment: @sstan - I have updated my question with one query which is slightly incorrect but explains my requirement

Comment: I get that the query is not 100% accurate, but in order to understand it, can you make the column names match your sample data?  For instance, your query includes a `person_id` column. Where does that come from? Please read the question from our perspective. Do you see why it's not easy to understand? Here are some ideas to improve the question: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Comment: @sstan - I have changed the query. Hopefully you can provide an input now ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gives you an idea on how to make a function for your problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WaterIsNotBlue (nId IN VARCHAR2, nColumnA IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    CURSOR cTableA IS
        SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Id = nId;

    rTableA cTableA%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Fetch current values of row. 
    OPEN cTableA;
    FETCH cTableA INTO rTableA;
    CLOSE cTableA;

    INSERT INTO TableA(Id, ColumnA)
    VALUES(nId, nColumnA);

    COMMIT;

    -- Check if anything changed. 
    IF rTableA.ColumnA != nColumnA THEN
        RETURN 'A';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'B';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You can't use `insert` or `commit` in a function

Comment: In PL/SQL you can, I use it all the time. I don't know about SQL though.

Comment: You can do that in a **procedure** but not in a _function_.

Comment: You make me thinking, so I tested it out. And I can compile this function and use it on a PLSQL database.

Comment: And can you _run_ it? You should get an "*ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   We can use DML in functions, but we can't use such functions  in queries.
Just try to execute this function from an anonymous block and all will be OK.

Comment: is there a necessity to use another db table ? already the data is there in two

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a trigger to detect the changes .. but through the trigger you can only insert into a new table the information that you want (effective_Start date and name).